# Calling telethon's send_message method with comment_to parameter behaves differently on some channels

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am using `send_message` method with `comment_to` parameter to effetively leave comments in public channels using telethon library.

Usually that behaves as expected but sometimes there is additional reply to original post.
[image: screenshot]

I dislike this unexpected behavior and I don't how to detect that leaving comment would be normal or not on one particular channel before posting it. Can you please help me to figure out that. Also it would be great to know how to make leaving comments always consistent without additional reply being encountered